# How to enter multi-line strings in REST Client for VS Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, rest, express

**EDIT** There's some confusion about what I am storing. I am making a code snippet web app in Express.js and Mongodb. I am not storing code to execute it later, I am storing it, and then displaying it in plain-text on the web app, and will allow the user to copy the code to use themselves. I have a syntax highlighter module installed to make it look good, but the code itself is not executed.

It is similar to GitHub Gists.

**Another Edit** How can I store multi-line text in Mongodb, then when fetched from server, convert it automatically to use \n for line breaks, and \t for tabs?

I am making a REST API in Express.js. I am using Rest Client extension in VS Code to test out the API.

I am making a post request to the server to create a code snippet. The fields for the snippet model are all strings, but I need one field to hold actual code inside it. I tried using backticks and a few other things, but cannot seem to figure it out.

Here's my file "api.rest"

```
@hostname = localhost
@port = 5000
@host = {{hostname}}:{{port}}
@contentType = application/json

# POST /users
POST http://{{host}}/snippets HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: {{contentType}}

{
    "title": "React Component",
    "code": "CHANGE THIS TO A MULTI-LINE JAVASCRIPT CODE SNIPPET",
    "creator": "nero1333"
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what file format this is, but I assume just putting in `\n` every time you need a newline character will probably work. However, I really hope your API endpoint is not going to simply execute any random string of code that is sent from any client - that's a huge security nono.

Comment: Well, I am making a web app in express.js to store code snippets in MongoDB. How would you suggest I store code? I'm happy you brought this up so I can learn how to solve this problem. Any hints or examples you could send my way about how to store code in MongoDB, please let me know

Comment: I'd take a step back. Why do you think you need to store code? This is getting way off topic but while simply storing code doesn't in itself cause any harm, the problem is when you come to *execute* that code, which I presume you'll eventually want to do otherwise why store it? And executing code on your server that can come from any random untrusted user is a Bad Idea for reasons that I hope are really obvious (just look back at all the news about log4j from the past couple of weeks, which shows what can happen when you allow this).

Comment: @PrestonCammarata depends on your use case, should be fine as long as you don't attempt to execute that user-inputted code

Comment: No. I am not storing code to execute it. I am storing code which will be displayed in plain-text on the web app. It will allow you to click a button to copy the code, so you can use it elsewhere. It's a simple code snippet web app. Just storing code in plaintext.

Comment: It's similar to GitHub Gists.

Comment: @PrestonCammarata yeah, then what you have should be fine, just use `\n` to create multiline json strings

Comment: Is it possible to store a multi-line string in Mongodb, then when its fetched from db, I can convert the new lines to use /n and tabs with /t? It needs to be dynamic.

Comment: Also, I get an error using \n. My code is: "code": "import React from 'react'\nclass className extends React.Component\n\trender() {\n\t\t<div></div>\n\t}"

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is very simple. You just want to save text input in the database and fetch it later to display on the client-side.

You just have to send the code in string form containing `\n` for a new line, `\t` for tabs, and `\"` to escape the double quotes used in the code.

If you are taking input from a text editor using a webpage, that editor will escape these values for you and you will send it to the server to store.

**For example:**

You want to save this code as you mentioned in the comment:

```
import React from 'react'
class className extends React.Component
    render() {
        <div></div>
    }
```

Send it like:

```
{
    "code": "import React from 'react'\nclass className extends React.Component\n\trender() {\n\t\t<div></div>\n\t}"
}
```

Same way you will enter it in the REST client to test the API.